# Black Screen with cursor blinking when started Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox

Ubuntu on my Virtual Machine was running fine when I restarted then suddenly it starts showing a black screen. I googled and tried multiple solutions like:

1. by disabling the "Enable 3D acceleration" on virtualBox settings
2. Enabling the "Intel Virtualization Technology" from BIOS

Please note, when I used backup Ubuntu, it works fine. My host system is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. VirtualBox Version 6.0.12, Ubuntu guest OS in VirtualBox is 18.04.2.

I will appreciate if you can help to address the issue

Comment: I had the same problem, but more severe as it was not on a virtual machine. Somehow the developers managed to put amdgpu out of operation at least since 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I am able to resolve the issue.

I was trying to access the USB. The black screen problem occurred, when I added the "Generic USB2.0-CRW [3960]" FROM VirtualBox Settings -> USB -> "add new USB filter...". I selected USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller from "Enable USB Controller" section.

As soon I removed the  "Generic USB2.0-CRW [3960]", connected my USB bug and selected "FTDI FT232R USB UART [0600]", I was able to connect my switch using minicom.

I am not sure yet why this problem happened!